# EF Code First and Db Owner

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first

I have a problem that might be simple but I can't find anything about it.

I'm using EF 4.1 Code First on a legacy db. In our development environment, all tables are under "dbo" owner, but in production some are under another user, let's say "myuser".

I am mapping my object with method "ToTable" specifing only the table name without the owner. This way, EF automatically tries to go on [dbo].[TableName] and in production throws an invalid object name error, as the table is [myuser].[TableName]

Is there a way to tell EF to ignore the db owner when mapping tables? I can't change owners in production environment, and I can't replicate for other reasons the production configuration in our development db.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the schema at runtime.

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<SomeOtherObject> SomeOtherObjects { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<YetAnotherObject> YetMoreObjects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RuntimeSchemaConfiguration<SomeObject>());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RuntimeSchemaConfiguration<SomeOtherObject>());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RuntimeSchemaConfiguration<YetAnotherObject>());
    }

    private class RuntimeSchemaConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
        where T : class
    {
        public RuntimeSchemaConfiguration()
        {
            // Rename the schema based on a string
            // from a config file or other source
            var schemaName = GetSchemaNameFromConfigFile();
            ToTable(typeof(T).Name, schemaName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out tomorrow, and I'll let you know. Thanks.